# How to create or custom bibliography styles for to use with biblatex/Rstudio/knitr/Sweave

Tags: styles, knitr, rstudio, bibliography, biblatex

I am using biblatex with bibtex in backend (MikTex) for generating dynamic statistical reports with knitr (sweave) in Rstudio which is realy a great combination of tools. 
I have with difficulty created my own bibliography style (.bst file) with custom-bib (for British Journal of Neurosurgery)
Unfortunately, .bst files doesnt work with biblatex and custom-bib is not a very pratical tool. More over knitr/Rstudio doesn't work with biber. I haven't try to create manually my own style as it seems quite complicated.
I will have to create more styles for publishing in medicals journals which have often their own bibliography style.

My Questions are: 
How can I easily create or customize bibliography styles for to use with  biblatex/Rstudio/knitr/Sweave ?
I have briefly and unsuccessfully try with Jabref, Bib-it.
The only practicale solution I have found is to create my own style with CSL Visual Editor and then secondary use it with Zotero/ Mendeley in a .odt document after having converted my Rsweave PDF document in a .odt file.
I search extensively the web without finding THE solution.
Any clue ?
Thanks

Comment: You might be better off at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: R/RStudio/knitr work well with bibtex and custom .bst files that can be found on the texmf paths, but not well with biblatex/biber as you discovered.